# How to execute a shell script that has mount command inside dockerfile

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I have a Dockerfile and additional_req.sh file. After building docker from dockerfile, I run the docker in privileged mode and execute this shell script as it contains mount commands. Now I need to perform this process inside dockerfile for some reason. Is there any way to achieve this? I want to run all the instructions in dockerfile itself. I should not run an additional command.

I tried the following but failed

used `EXECUTE` command - but an additional step of docker run is required

used `RUN` command - failed with permission denied error at mount command

used `CMD` command - failed with the same error as the RUN command.

Comment: Please describe the mount commands in additional_req.sh file

Comment: `mount binfmt_misc -t binfmt_misc /proc/sys/fs/binfmt_misc/`
`mount proc <chroot_dir>/proc -t proc`
They are like these

Comment: Btw, It would be great if you changed the question title to something that more accurately reflects what you're trying to do. You have managed to run a shell script in the Dockerfile. You just haven't managed to run the mount command in a dockerfile. This way, people who can't get arbitrary shell scripts running in their dockerfile aren't  mislead by the question title.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't mount filesystems at all inside a Dockerfile.  In general you're prevented from running **mount**(8) inside Docker.

A Docker image only persists the filesystem and some metadata describing how to run a container from it.  It does not include any mounted filesystems or kernel-level settings.  If you were able to `RUN mount`, that change wouldn't last beyond the end of the current `RUN` command.  In the particular case of the system-level settings in `/proc`, those have the potential to leak outside of Docker space (since the kernel is shared between the host and all containers) and wouldn't survive a reboot or the image being copied to another system.

More generally, Docker uses Linux [capabilities](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/capabilities.7.html) to prevent many system-level operations.  There are [`docker run` options to add capabilities to a container](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/#runtime-privilege-and-linux-capabilities), but needing these is very rare and they can't be added to the build step.  If you really needed to mount something, you'd have to do it in your container startup, and you'd have to run the container with the very broad `docker run --cap-add SYS_ADMIN` or `docker run --privileged` options.

In a comment you talk about changing system-level settings in `/proc/sys/fs`.  Since Docker doesn't provide kernel-level isolation, you might be better off running this task in a virtual machine, at which point you could use some sort of init script or put this setup in the VM's `/proc/mounts` file.